# Help needed in finding coordinate count

Tags: c#

I have an 8 X 8 matrix.  Now, The below coordinates are occupied

`{ 6, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 3, 3 }....` What needs to be done is that, I need to build straight line

through these points and needs to count how many coordinates they have touched?

My program so far stands as

```
private static void GetCount(int[,] Positions)
{

    int rcount = 8;
    int firstRow = Positions[0, 0];            

    for (int i = 1; i < Positions.Length/2; i++)
    {              
       int currentRow = Positions[i, 0];
       if (currentRow != firstRow)
        {
          rcount += 8;
          firstRow = currentRow;
        }      
     }

     int cCount = 8;
     int firstCol = Positions[0, 1];

     for (int i = 1; i < Positions.Length / 2; i++)
     {


        int currentCol = Positions[i, 1];
        if (currentCol != firstCol)
        {
            cCount += 8;
            firstCol = currentCol;
         }

      }
     int totalCount = rcount - cCount;
     Console.WriteLine(totalCount);

}
```

And I am invoking it as

```
GetCount(new int[,] { { 6, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 3, 3 } });
```

The output will be 40 here. (count will be 24 for each 3 unique rows i.e. 6,5,3 and count will be 16 for 2 unique columns i.e. 3 and 5... So, the total count is 24+16 = 40)
But I am getting the output as 48.

**Also  is it possible to do the porgram using one single loop?**

I am using C# 1.0

Edited

This does work

```
List<int> lstRows = new List<int>();
            List<int> lstCols = new List<int>();
            int count = 0;

            //Get the unique rows and columns
            for (int i = 0; i < marinePositions.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                if (!lstRows.Contains(marinePositions[i, 0])) lstRows.Add(Positions[i, 0]);
                if (!lstCols.Contains(marinePositions[i, 1])) lstCols.Add(Positions[i, 1]);
            }
            //get row count
            for (int i = 0; i < lstRows.Count; i++) count += 8;
            //get column count
            for (int i = 0; i < lstCols.Count; i++) count += 8;

            Console.WriteLine(count);
```

But need a much better one.. if possible using linq/lambda and no loop

Please help

Comment: Isn't the correct answer should be 38 ? because when counting for y cordinate we have to count 7 and not 8 as there is one count overlapped while doing for x cordinate

Comment: How can a straight line go through three points which don't occur on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here u go... but this in is LINQ and not C# 1.0 which is way too old.. not sure why are you using such old version of the language:

```
        private static void GetCount(int[,] Positions)
        {
            List<int> x = new List<int>();
            List<int> y = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Positions.Length/2; i++)
            {
                x.Add(Positions[i, 0]);
                y.Add(Positions[i, 1]);
            }
            int result = (x.Distinct().Count() * 8) + (y.Distinct().Count() * 8);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

No loops magic:

```
    private static void GetCount(int[,] Positions)
    {
        var range = Enumerable.Range(0, Positions.Length / 2);
        var result = (range.Select(i => Positions[i, 0]).Distinct().Count() * 8) +
                     (range.Select(i => Positions[i, 1]).Distinct().Count() * 8);
        Console.WriteLine(result);

    }
```

Comment: But that does not give the correct output..my edited asnwer is above

Comment: See my new updated code for "no loops magic" as you have asked in your updated question

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTIONS:

1-

```
int cCount = 8;
```

To:

```
int cCount = 0;
```

2-

```
int totalCount = rcount - cCount;
```

To:

```
int totalCount = rcount + cCount;
```

The program should work fine now.

Comment: It fails for { 5,5 }, { 5, 3 }.. the output will be 24